# Maven package in-project repository dependencies inside jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-dependency-plugin, uberjar

I am using the in-project repository dependency solution to include a third party jar as a dependency in my Maven project. I'm following the instructions on [this blog](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/01/maven-in-project-repository.html) for that.

Now, I want that when I package my Maven project into a jar, the jar that is created should have a lib folder with the third party jar in it. However, I do NOT want the other dependencies to be packaged in the jar. (I don't want a fat jar with ALL dependencies packaged inside it, I just want a jar with the one third party dependency jar packaged inside it).

I have been trying to play around with the maven-dependency-plugin and the maven-jar-plugin, but I've not been able to achieve what I want.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `maven-dependency-plugin` (look [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)) as shown below, this plugin will provide lots of options to include jars which ArtifactId (i.e., `<includeArtifactIds>`) or groupId (`<includeGroupIds>`), etc...

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>copy-dependencies</id>
             <phase>prepare-package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/
                             classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <includeArtifactIds>YOUR_THIRDPARTY_JAR_NAME</includeArtifactIds>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

So, the **above code will add `YOUR_THIRDPARTY_JAR_NAME.jar` into your final `.jar` file's `lib` folder**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet). It allows filtering included dependencie, so you can choose what deps to include in the assembly